# Bluetooth no longer working?

Tags: bluetooth

I am using a Toshiba Portege A600 and have been using Ubuntu for about a year now. When I first installed Ubuntu "10.10", everything worked fine, including bluetooth. I was able to send and receive files. After upgrading to 11.04 and then to 11.10, bluetooth functionality decreased. I was able to view bluetooth devices, but not be able to pair or connect to them. Now, on 12.04, bluetooth is no longer recognised at all. When I open up the Bluetooth settings application, it says "No Bluetooth Adapters found". What is the cause of this, and how can I fix it.

I have included the output of sudo lshw.

http://pastebin.com/09w0vkfu

Thanks!

Comment: Consider pasting all relevant text into the question, and don't require on external links. This isn't IRC and when that link dies this question will be useless.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command in your teminal by using `ctrl+alt+t`

```
sudo -s -H
service bluetooth stop
rmmod btusb
rmmod ath3k
modprobe -a ath3k
echo "13d3 3304" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/ath3k/new_id
modprobe btusb
service bluetooth start
```

Hope this will work!!!

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm running a dual boot with Windows 7, and I have read that if bluetooth is disabled in Windows, it can affect Ubuntu. I installed the bluetooth stack for Windows, and although it is buggy, it works. The command didn't work, and I got this when running the 3rd and fourth lines:
`root@administrator-PORTEGE-A600:/home/administrator# rmmod btusb

ERROR: Module btusb does not exist in /proc/modules

root@administrator-PORTEGE-A600:/home/administrator# rmmod ath3k

ERROR: Module ath3k does not exist in /proc/modules
`

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 12.10 i config it in dconf

search crtl+f and put bluetooth

enable all items and restart your PC.

in my laptop was the same thing that happens whit you and now i receive and send everything!!!

i hope to that it solve your problem!!!

Comment: The steps that you provided are not very clear. Could you please give better instructions to follow?